# Expected money won in $30$ coin flips, if heads win you $5$ dollars and tails lose you $4$

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I would appreciate help with my exam studying. A question asks:

If we flip a coin 30 times, with every **head** winning 5 dollars and for every **tail** losing 4 dollars. What is the expected value $E(W)$ of $W$, with $W$ being the random variable amount of money you would win.

What I think it is:

$$E(W) = 30\cdot5\frac{1}{2^{30}} + 30\cdot(-4)\frac{1}{2^{30}}$$

Does this seem correct?

Thank you for help!

Comment: What does your intuition tell you?  If you flip this fair coin $n$ times, how many dollars do you expect to win?  Does this formula meet that intuition?

Comment: To me it makes sense, because I'm taking n flips and can either get head or tails n times (thus the 1/2^n). Then whether I win 5 or lose 4 dollars.

Comment: How many dollars do you expect to win?  $\$\,0.00000003$?

Comment: Ha, I guess not. John's answer explained to me why I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're independent events, so you can add the expected winning of one coin toss 30 times.  You expect to win 50 cents on each toss ($0.5 \times 5 + 0.5 \times -4$) so the expected value of your winnings after 30 coin tosses is $30 \times 0.5 = 15 \text{ dollars}.$

Comment: Thank you so much :)! Makes sense to me!

Comment: "They're independent events, so you can add the expected winning(s)" Expectation is additive whether independence holds or not.